# Is there a way to predict a 'classname' attribute that is visible in junitxml generated by pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

How does pytest construct a value of 'classname' attribute in junitxml?

For example it seems like changing a working directory from which tests are run has impact on a 'classname' attribute.

Example:

There is a test in `~/test_pytest/A/AA/a.py`.

I run it using `pytest ~/test_pytest/A/AA/a.py --junitxml=b`

When I run it from `~/test_pytest` the junitxml contains `<testcase classname="A.AA.a" file="A/AA/a.py" line="1" name="test_tt" time="0.000">`

When I run it from `/tmp` the junitxml contains `<testcase classname="a" file="a.py" line="1" name="test_tt" time="0.000">`

Comment: can you give an example? also you can customize the name of the `classname` attribute if you want

Comment: @aws_apprentice I added an example.

Comment: looks like it is just adding the path to the file, you can override that by using this --> http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#record-xml-attribute

Comment: @aws_apprentice Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot edit these tests in any way.